# Why does android studio gives NullPointerException while initializing Buttons, EditText and SwitchCompats?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am a beginner in android studio and working on a project similar to Uber application.I am stuck in a bug for hours in Welcome activity that whenever compiler reaches the line where EditText is initialized and then setFocusable() method is called on EditText then NullPointerException is thrown on that line. I tried commenting that part of code. But when another button is initialized in later part of code and onClickListener is called then again NullPointerException is thrown.Again when both are commented then NullPointerException is thrown on usage of SwitchCompat. In short, android studio is not initializing any field. It is throwing NullPointerException on every field. I also tried using ButterKnife library but in vain.
Below is welcome_activity.xml where you can see ids are named correctly.
Suggestions and guidance are appreciated.

That is activity Welcome.java

```
package com.anonymous.uberedmt;

    private Button btnGo;
    private EditText places;
   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
            callPermissions();

            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            locationCallback = new LocationCallback();
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error: ", "nkn");
        }

        polyLineList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Places Autocomplete
        **places = findViewById( R.id.edt_Place);
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "API-KEY");
        places.setFocusable(false);**

        places.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Initialize Place-Field List
                List<Place.Field> fieldList = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.NAME);
                Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fieldList).build(Welcome.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACES_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        **btnGo = findViewById(R.id.btn_Go);**
        btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                destination = places.getText().toString();
                destination = destination.replace(" ", "+"); //Replace space with plus to fetch data
                Log.d("ShARRY", destination);

                getDirection();
            }
        });


        **location_switch = findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
        location_switch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {**
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (location_switch.isChecked()) {
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    displayLocation();
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(), "You are Online", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                    if(mCurrent != null)
                        mCurrent.remove();
                    mMap.clear();
                    handler = new Handler();
                    handler.removeCallbacks(drawPathRunnable);
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(), "You are Offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Here is activity_welcome.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_panel"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        <EditText
            **android:id="@+id/edt_Place"**
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/enter_pickup_location"/>
 <Button
            **android:id="@+id/btn_Go"**
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/go"/>

        
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_panel"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.anonymous.uberedmt.Welcome"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_welcome" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                **android:id="@+id/location_switch"**
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textOff="@drawable/ic_location_off"
                android:textOn="@drawable/ic_location_on" />

            <Button
                **android:id="@+id/btn_find_user"**
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:text="@string/find_user" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anonymous.uberedmt"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-java:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
}
```

Here is Project-level gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url 'http://maven.google.com'
        }

        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.anonymous.uberedmt, PID: 28835
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anonymous.uberedmt/com.anonymous.uberedmt.Welcome}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.anonymous.uberedmt.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:255)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28835 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Why is the first part of your `onCreate()` in a `try`-`catch`? Are you sure nothing's going wrong there? Remove that, and see what crashes your app then.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah there is an android.view.InflateException there. I have found only way to remove it is to handle it using try-catch structure

Comment: That means that the `setContentView()` call is failing. That's the actual problem. Avoiding the Exception didn't solve it; it just moved the problem further down the line.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for suggestion. I will check this.